# pass multiple(distinct) values to and single attribute in a iteration JMeter

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing

Unable to pass multiple values in a single iteration from csv config data set

1. POST Body :-

[{"customerOrderId": "WS_${_*RandomString(5,ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890,)}", "shipFromLocationId": "${ship_from_location}", "deliveryDate": "${expected_arrival_date}Z", "deliveryLatestDate": "${expected_arrival_date}Z", "packId": "${pack_id}", **"itemId": "${item_id}**", "type": "fresh", "itemDescription": "${random_text}", "quantityOrdered": "${qty_ordered}", "quantityType": "CS", "createdAt": "${current_time}Z"},
{"customerOrderId": "WS*${_*RandomString(5,ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890,)}", "shipFromLocationId": "${ship_from_location}", "deliveryDate": "${expected_arrival_date}Z", "deliveryLatestDate": "${expected_arrival_date}Z", "packId": "${pack_id}", **"itemId": "${item_id}"**, "type": "fresh", "itemDescription": "${random_text}", "quantityOrdered": "${qty_ordered}", "quantityType": "CS", "createdAt": "${current_time}Z"},
{"customerOrderId": "WS*${__RandomString(5,ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890,)}", "shipFromLocationId": "${ship_from_location}", "deliveryDate": "${expected_arrival_date}Z", "deliveryLatestDate": "${expected_arrival_date}Z", "packId": "${pack_id}", **"itemId": "${item_id}"**, "type": "fresh", "itemDescription": "${random_text}", "quantityOrdered": "${qty_ordered}", "quantityType": "CS", "createdAt": "${current_time}Z"}]

2. CSV Data File

[image]

Column 2 is itemId , i need different itemID in a single iteration. As body contains different itemId, i need to make sure it has different item id from csv

How can I achieve this? as with csv data set config I don't see any option to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

Given default [CSV Data Set Config Sharing Mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-csv-dataset-config) of `All Threads` each virtual user will read next line from the csv file on each iteration.

If you want to read several lines within the bounds of a single iteration - you will need to consider switching to [__CSVRead() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) instead

Replace `${item_id}` with `${__CSVRead(test.csv,1)}${__CSVRead(test.csv,next)}`

```
[
  {
    "customerOrderId": "WS_${_RandomString(5,ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890,)}",
    "shipFromLocationId": "${ship_from_location}",
    "deliveryDate": "${expected_arrival_date}Z",
    "deliveryLatestDate": "${expected_arrival_date}Z",
    "packId": "${pack_id}",
    "itemId": "${__CSVRead(test.csv,1)}${__CSVRead(test.csv,next)}",
    "type": "fresh",
    "itemDescription": "${random_text}",
    "quantityOrdered": "${qty_ordered}",
    "quantityType": "CS",
    "createdAt": "${current_time}Z"
  },
  {
    "customerOrderId": "WS${_RandomString(5,ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890,)}",
    "shipFromLocationId": "${ship_from_location}",
    "deliveryDate": "${expected_arrival_date}Z",
    "deliveryLatestDate": "${expected_arrival_date}Z",
    "packId": "${pack_id}",
    "itemId": "${__CSVRead(test.csv,1)}${__CSVRead(test.csv,next)}",
    "type": "fresh",
    "itemDescription": "${random_text}",
    "quantityOrdered": "${qty_ordered}",
    "quantityType": "CS",
    "createdAt": "${current_time}Z"
  },
  {
    "customerOrderId": "WS${__RandomString(5,ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890,)}",
    "shipFromLocationId": "${ship_from_location}",
    "deliveryDate": "${expected_arrival_date}Z",
    "deliveryLatestDate": "${expected_arrival_date}Z",
    "packId": "${pack_id}",
    "itemId": "${__CSVRead(test.csv,1)}${__CSVRead(test.csv,next)}",
    "type": "fresh",
    "itemDescription": "${random_text}",
    "quantityOrdered": "${qty_ordered}",
    "quantityType": "CS",
    "createdAt": "${current_time}Z"
  }
]
```

again, replace `test.csv` with either relative or full path to your CSV file.